# Host as Pid namespace in Docker

Tags: docker, namespaces

How sharing(files or other related things) happens when Docker uses the host in pid-namespaces? and Is there any limitations of using it?

Comment: Sharing between the container and its host? Or between containers on different hosts?

Comment: Mainly between container and its host.

Answer (score 2):

There are total 6 namespaces currently implemented in Linux Kernel and Docker support them partially RunC is more advanced in that. Non of those namespaces limits Filesystem in particular.

Docker does `chroot` into given image mounted layer file system (devicemapper or aufs) to limit access to file system from containerized process.

So by mounting (using `-v`) you can expose part of you host file system (or all of it with `/`) to containerized process.

There are no particular limitation to that in terms of performance and usage (it's negligible) except some limitation that `aufs` itlsef for example might expose and those are very rare cases.

If you need more detailed explanation on a specific topic please give us more information.

Comment: How the Docker use the Host as pid-namespace any limitations from the side of host?